# ViewPager swipe with 2 fingers

Tags: android, android-viewpager, touch-event

I would to implement a ViewPager swipe with two fingers.
I tried to implement a sublcass of ViewPager overriding the onTouchEvent and passing the method to superclass only if the touch is made by 2 fingers.
But there is a problem: the swipe animation also works with 1 finger!
I think I have to override some other method...

This is my ViewPager class:

```
public class MyViewPager extends ViewPager{
public MyViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MyViewPager(Context context,AttributeSet attributeSet) {
    super(context,attributeSet);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    int n = ev.getPointerCount(); //number of fingers
    if (n == 2)
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    else return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overriding `onInterceptTouchEvent()` should do the trick. According to the comments in the [`ViewPager` sources](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java#ViewPager.onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29), it's there where the decision is made whether scrolling should start or not.

Comment: @SaravanaKumarChinnaraj overriding onInterceptTouchEvent() but there were many problems. Actually I didn't be able to make it work well, so, at that time, I found another solution.

Comment: what was that solution..? @fran

Comment: I didn't use ViewPager.

Comment: @SaravanaKumarChinnaraj eheh... there were also other factors that led me to find another solution: the swipe with 2 fingers is very "user un-friendly"

Answer (score 1):

im writing this code and its working for two finger .

```
boolean freeTwo = false;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    final int action = ev.getAction() & MotionEventCompat.ACTION_MASK;
    int counter = ev.getPointerCount() ;

    if(counter == 1 && (action== MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || action== MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) && !freeTwo)
    {
        if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
            freeTwo = true;
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    if(counter == 2 && (action== MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN|| action== MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE || action== MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) && freeTwo)
    {
        if(action== MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP)
            freeTwo = false;
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    ev.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP);
    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}
```