# ViewPager swipe with 2 fingers not working

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a question similar to this one:
[ViewPager swipe with 2 fingers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23806602/viewpager-swipe-with-2-fingers)

But the solution given doesn't work, the touch is always intercepted by the listview i have and the fragment doesn't change. I have 2 fragments, both with listviews. 
It works fine if i remove the code for two finger validation.

Regards !